# Error al instalar build-essential, Ubuntu 18.4.5

Tags: ubuntu, instalacion

Cuando entro a la terminal de mi ubuntu18.4 para instalar build-essential me sale el siguiente error:
(Es una droplet/vps)

Utilice el comando: apt-get install build-essential (Estaba como usuario root)

```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install build-essential
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                                libc-dev
                       Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

He probado instalarlo con: apt-get -y install build-essential, Y he recibido el mismo error.

También he intentado lo siguiente:

- apt-get install libc6-dev

  ```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install libc6-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- apt-get install libc-dev-bin

  ```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install libc-dev-bin
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.24) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
                    Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- apt-get install manpages-dev

  ```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install manpages-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     manpages-dev : Depends: manpages but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- sudo apt-get install g++

  ```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install g++
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     g++ : Depends: g++-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev

  ```
    root@pablo:~# apt-get install dpkg-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.18.4ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```

Al ejecutar:

- dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

  ```
    root@pablo:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
    root@pablo:~#
  ```

(La salida es nula, no tiene salida...)

Como puedo instalar build-essential?

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor ejecuta `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` y añade la salida a tu pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo ya lo hice, Al ejecutar ese comando no obtuve ninguna salida..., También ejecute ``grep hold`` por separado pero de igual forma no obtuve ninguna salida, se queda congelado como si el comando se estuviera ejecutando pero sin arrojar nada.

Comment: ¿Hiciste **apt-get update** antes de intentar instalar las build-essentials? Es práctica habitual también hacer **apt-get upgrade -Y** antes de instalar otro software nuevo.

Comment: @V.Lorz No, no lo hice. Lo acabo de hacer hace un momento pero al parecer no había nada que actualizar, la maquina es nueva, es una droplet/vps

Comment: Prueba con los pasos recomendados [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/a/484761). Lo que ellos plantean tiene sentido, puedes tener conflictos de versiones.